# Should there be duplicate information in my path on my mac?

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I used this command multiple times

```
export PATH=“/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:$PATH”
```

Now it seems this caused me to have duplicate information in my `$PATH`.

```
echo $PATH
“/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:??:/usr/local/mysql@5.7/bin:“/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:??:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

Initially, `mysql.server` command does not work. How do I get rid of duplicate information?

I saw some code that resets the `$PATH` but I don't want to delete the entire thing, just part of it.

```
export PATH=“/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:$PATH”
echo $PATH
“/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:??:/usr/local/mysql@5.7/bin:“/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:??:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

Actual

```
echo $PATH
“/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:??:/usr/local/mysql@5.7/bin:“/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:??:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

Expected

```
echo $PATH
“/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin
```

I think.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40755/333919

Comment: Don't use curly quotes when programming, just ASCII single and double quotes.

Comment: The curly quotes are the main problem here. Duplicate entries are slightly inefficient,  but don't fundamentally break anything. Curly quotes break things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only downside to having duplicate sections of `PATH` is slightly longer times to search through everything; it won't hurt you.

Your `PATH` as written is broken, it should not contain quotes.

You can change your path by simply copy-pasting the correct parts and doing another `export PATH=`...

Comment: @jhnc The question marks are a result of the wrong quotes (unicode instead of plain ASCII), and a bash oddity in how it treats a multibyte character at the end of a variable reference. Specifically, it treats the first *byte* as part of the variable name, giving an invalid name followed by invalid UTF-8. See my answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/296902/what-makes-the-bash-interpreter-utility-interpret-differently-standard-and-smart/296908#296908).

Comment: Thank you @jeremysprofile that fixed my problem. I just delete the quotes and did it again.